What changes does the web.config file need while upgrading from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.8?
I want to upgrade .NET Framework version from 4.5 to 4.8. This is for a Web Forms (.aspx) project
I have these sections in the (current) web.config file

I want to understand what these settings represent.
Should I modify them in order to upgrade to .NET Framework version 4.8?
If so, what should the new values look like?

<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

